# Как правильно выстроить связи в БД банка

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Всем привет!
Я создал БД банка, в которой нужно прописать связи между сущностями ФИЗ ЛИЦО, КРЕДИТЫ, ВКЛАДЫ, КРЕДИТЫ, ТИПА КРЕДИТОВ. А также прописать бизнес версионность.

На приложенной схеме я описал все перечисленные сущности и связи между ними. Отмечу что сущность CONTRACTS имеет уникальный номер для каждого клиента и является по моему плану договором между банком и клиентом, подразумевающая что клиент в принципе обслуживается в банке. К этому договору подвязано неограниченное кол-во договоров кредитования для этого клиента и неограниченное кол-во договоров вкладов, каждый из которых будет иметь свой уникальный номер.

Финализирую вопросы

1. Подскажите, пожалуйста, верно ли проставлены связи между всеми обозначенными сущностями?
2. К каким записям (строкам) я могу дописать бизнес версионность? Под бизнес-версионностью я подразумеваю наличие в сущности двух доп столбцов: date_start и date_end.

[image: ОБНОВЛЕННАЯ БД]

Comment: надо учитывать, что у клиента может быть несколько контрактов (счетов)

Comment: контракт (договор) у клиента с банком может быть не один. например, договоров на депозит у клиента может быть несколько. понятие регистрация клиента в банке для доступа к ,например,  разным его каналам (интернет,смс,почта и тп) совсем другое и никак не связана с контрактом.

Comment: вполне имеет. по версионности стоит рассматривать кредиты и вклады